# Expanding the series ...

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

Here we have such a sequence $x_n$. The thing that I do not understand is the following: where does the right side of this equality come from, how is it formed ? Can you please show me the operation hidden behind the right side of the following:

Thank you

$x_{2n}-x_{n}={1\over n+1}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot +{1\over  2n} $
.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the observation.

Comment: @JohnG., please edit the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $\displaystyle x_{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{1}+...+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n}$.

Now we can write $\displaystyle x_{2n}-\left(\frac{1}{1}+...+\frac{1}{n} \right)+\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n} \Rightarrow x_{2n}-x_n=\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n}$

Comment: Can I ask you one more question, please ?

Comment: Go for it, buddy.

Answer (score 1):

$$x_{2n}-x_n=\sum^{2n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}-\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}=(1+\frac{1}{2}+..+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n})-(1+\frac{1}{2}+..+\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$ then this implies that $x_{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}$. Therefore:$$x_{2n}-x_n=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$$$$=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$$$$=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}$$